# ajax response data is not showing on html table inside modal in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a link when i click on the link opening the modal and calling the ajax method.It is opening the Modal and calling the ajax method and getting the response data fine but not displaying the data which coming from the ajax response on my modal inside table.I tried so many ways but it is not working.Now I fixed the syntax errors Please somebody help me .thanks in Advance.

### HTML code

```js
function Showdata() {
    $("#showdata").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        title: 'table',
        width: '1190',
        height: '630',
        buttons: {
            Cancel: function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        },
    }).dialog('open');
    return false;
}

var response=[{
    "mtrl_id": "1",
    "mtrl_name": "Iron Sticks",
    "mtrl_uom": "150",
    "mtrl_price": "1700",
    "mtrl_slno": "iron15",
    "mtrl_maxstk": "1700",
    "mtrl_crtstk": "160",
    "mtrl_stkonorder": "190",
    "mtrl_insertat": "2018-02-20 15:18:44.000000",
    "mtrl_updt": "2018-02-22 10:24:59.000000"
}, {
    "mtrl_id": "5",
    "mtrl_name": "Cement Bags",
    "mtrl_uom": "1500",
    "mtrl_price": "6400",
    "mtrl_slno": "cm165",
    "mtrl_maxstk": "1400",
    "mtrl_crtstk": "120",
    "mtrl_stkonorder": "200",
    "mtrl_insertat": "2018-02-20 14:48:17.000000",
    "mtrl_updt": "2018-02-21 18:13:14.000000"
},  {
    "mtrl_id": "9",
    "mtrl_name": "Beans",
    "mtrl_uom": "15",
    "mtrl_price": "161",
    "mtrl_slno": "sls12",
    "mtrl_maxstk": "150",
    "mtrl_crtstk": "120",
    "mtrl_stkonorder": "116",
    "mtrl_insertat": "2018-02-21 17:43:01.000000",
    "mtrl_updt": "2018-02-21 18:22:40.000000"
}]


$(function(){
  $('#showdiv a').on('click',function(){
      $.ajax({
        data:response,
        success:function(response) {
           var dat=response;
           var tbody=$("#Mytbl tbody"),
          // var tbody =$("#mtrlform").find('#tablediv #Mytbl tbody'),
               prop = ["mtrl_name", "mtrl_uom","mtrl_maxstk","mtrl_crtstk"];
               $.each(dat, function(i, dat) {
                 var tr = $('<tr>');
                 $.each(prop, function(i, prop) {
                  $('<td>').html(dat[prop]).appendTo(tr);
                 });
                   $('<td>').html("<a class='editdata' onclick='OpeneditModal();'' href='"+dat["mtrl_id"]+"'><i class='fa fa-edit fa-2x'></i></a>").appendTo(tr);
                   $('<td>').html("<a class='removedata' href='"+dat["mtrl_id"]+"'><i class='fa fa-remove fa-2x'></i></a>").appendTo(tr);
               });
        }

    });

  });
});
```

```html
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id ="showdiv" style="width:20%;float:right;">
            <div style="font-size:18px;"><a onclick="Showdata();" href="#">Show Details</a></div>
          </div>
          <div id="showdata" style="display:none;">
          <div id="tablediv" style="width:100%;margin-top:10px;" max-height="500px;" overflow="auto;">
    
          <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-fixed" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%;padding-top:20px;" id="Mytbl">
          <thead>
            <tr>
            <th style="text-align:center;font-size:15px;">Name</th>
            <th style="text-align:center;font-size:15px;">UOM</th>
            <th style="text-align:center;font-size:15px;">Maxstock</th>
            <th style="text-align:center;font-size:15px;">Current Stock</th>
            <th style="text-align:center;font-size:15px;">Edit</th>
            <th style="text-align:center;font-size:15px;">Delete</th>
          </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
    
          </tbody>
          </table> 
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I won't see any use of $.ajax

Comment: `function() {
      
            success: function(responsedata) {` fail

Comment: `Please somebody help me MY js fiddle` - there's no link to a fiddle either

Comment: how to share the link please tellme

Comment: if you "run code snippet" ... see this: `Error:
{
  "message": "SyntaxError: expected expression, got '--'",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 56,
  "colno": 2
}` - your code is invalid syntax, so of course nothing will happen. Debugging 101 tip. Browsers have a ***developer** tools console* - which is a console that will display, amongst other things, syntax errors in your code, allowing you to fix simple syntax errors, before tackling logic errors

Comment: you can copy paste

Comment: Now I posted my ajax method please check nikhil

Comment: So, the response data you logged, shows correctly on the console? And I did not see the code to call Showdata() function. Maybe you need to call that at the end of your ajax call's success section.

Comment: You can see that code here <div id ="showdiv" style="width:20%;float:right;">
            <div style="font-size:18px;"><a onclick="Showdata();" href="#">Show Details</a></div>
          </div>

Comment: Some body check syntax errors fixed.Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this you have missed `tr.appendTo(tbody);` and if i have used your ajax then I am getting null value

```js
function Showdata() {
    $("#showdata").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        title: 'table',
        width: '1190',
        height: '630',
        buttons: {
            Cancel: function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        },
    }).dialog('open');
    return false;
}

var response=[{
    "mtrl_id": "1",
    "mtrl_name": "Iron Sticks",
    "mtrl_uom": "150",
    "mtrl_price": "1700",
    "mtrl_slno": "iron15",
    "mtrl_maxstk": "1700",
    "mtrl_crtstk": "160",
    "mtrl_stkonorder": "190",
    "mtrl_insertat": "2018-02-20 15:18:44.000000",
    "mtrl_updt": "2018-02-22 10:24:59.000000"
}, {
    "mtrl_id": "5",
    "mtrl_name": "Cement Bags",
    "mtrl_uom": "1500",
    "mtrl_price": "6400",
    "mtrl_slno": "cm165",
    "mtrl_maxstk": "1400",
    "mtrl_crtstk": "120",
    "mtrl_stkonorder": "200",
    "mtrl_insertat": "2018-02-20 14:48:17.000000",
    "mtrl_updt": "2018-02-21 18:13:14.000000"
},  {
    "mtrl_id": "9",
    "mtrl_name": "Beans",
    "mtrl_uom": "15",
    "mtrl_price": "161",
    "mtrl_slno": "sls12",
    "mtrl_maxstk": "150",
    "mtrl_crtstk": "120",
    "mtrl_stkonorder": "116",
    "mtrl_insertat": "2018-02-21 17:43:01.000000",
    "mtrl_updt": "2018-02-21 18:22:40.000000"
}]


$(function(){
  $('#showdiv a').on('click',function(){    
       
           var dat=response;
           var tbody=$("#Mytbl tbody"),
          // var tbody =$("#mtrlform").find('#tablediv #Mytbl tbody'),
   prop = ["mtrl_name", "mtrl_uom","mtrl_maxstk","mtrl_crtstk"];
               $.each(dat, function(i, dat) {
                
                 var tr = $('<tr>');
                 $.each(prop, function(i, prop) {    
                  $('<td>').html(dat[prop]).appendTo(tr);
                  tr.appendTo(tbody);
            });
                   $('<td>').html("<a class='editdata' onclick='OpeneditModal();'' href='"+dat["mtrl_id"]+"'><i class='fa fa-edit fa-2x'></i></a>").appendTo(tr);
                   $('<td>').html("<a class='removedata' href='"+dat["mtrl_id"]+"'><i class='fa fa-remove fa-2x'></i></a>").appendTo(tr);
               });     

  });
});
```

```css
td{
text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id ="showdiv" style="width:20%;float:right;">
            <div style="font-size:18px;"><a onclick="Showdata();" href="#">Show Details</a></div>
          </div>
          <div id="showdata" style="display:none;">
          <div id="tablediv" style="width:100%;margin-top:10px;" max-height="500px;" overflow="auto;">
    
          <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-fixed" cellspacing="0" border="1" style="width:100%;margin-top:50px;" id="Mytbl">
          <thead>
            <tr>
            <th style="text-align:center;font-size:15px;">Name</th>
            <th style="text-align:center;font-size:15px;">UOM</th>
            <th style="text-align:center;font-size:15px;">Maxstock</th>
            <th style="text-align:center;font-size:15px;">Current Stock</th>
            <th style="text-align:center;font-size:15px;">Edit</th>
            <th style="text-align:center;font-size:15px;">Delete</th>
          </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
    
          </tbody>
          </table> 
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me out .I have done the stupid mistake and i have wasted my full day.

Comment: My pleasue @itsme